# Why does hashset in c# allow adding of two objects with same values?

Tags: c#

```
    HashSet<List<int>> hs = new HashSet<List<int>>();
    
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
    list1.Add(1);
    list1.Add(2);
    
    List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
    list2.Add(1);
    list2.Add(2);
    
    hs.Add(list1);
    hs.Add(list2);
    
    Console.WriteLine(hs.Count);
```

The above code prints '2'. Should it not be '1'? The same in java will print '1'.

Comment: Because `List<int>` is a reference type, therefore, `list1 != list2`. You need to pass an `IEqualityComparer` to the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) of the HashSet if you want to have custom comparison logic.

Comment: Can you tell me why the same in java prints one? ArrayList<Integer> is also a reference type

Comment: I don't know if that's true in Java but assuming it is, the answer would be: because they're two different languages with two different sets of rules.

Comment: From the Javadoc for HashSet: "More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))". Essentially it calls .equals which probably has some kind of logic in it for comparing the elements of the array. C# doesn't really have a standard like .equals so is probably just checking whether they point to the same memory address.

Comment: adding to @WillMoffat comment, if you want your comparison to be done on the list's values instead of their reference, you could write your own IEqualityComparer that does so (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` (or rather `AbstractList`) in Java overrides the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. `HashSet` in Java uses `hashCode` and `equals` to determine the equality of two instances. Two lists with the same elements in the same order are considered equal.

HashSets in C# will use reference equality by default, therefore two list distinct instances are never equal. You need to provide the proper `IEqualityComparer` when constructing your HashSet.